# Multiply 2 columns and create a new one in n number of Dataframes in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have n number of csv files in a folder and converted them into pandas dataframes.

For all n dataframes I have, I would like to multiply the values of two columns and add values from another column (eg. (['X value'] * ['Slope']) + ['Intercept'])) and create a new column which will have the output Y values.

I have tried this way:

```
    dfs['Y value'] = [(dfs[n]['X value'] * dfs[n]['Slope']) + dfs[n]['Intercept'] for n in range(len(files))]
```

However it shows [y value] not in index as an error.

Thanks for your help. I'm new with Python and new here too, hope I explained my problem well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you mean to assign a y-value to each data frame.  The list comprehension is returning a list of values, not assigning to each `dfs[n]`.  The error happens because `dfs` is a list and needs to be indexed with a number.  To assign a y-value to each `dfs` do this:

```
for n in range(len(files)):
    dfs[n]['Y value'] = (dfs[n]['X value'] * dfs[n]['Slope']) + dfs[n]['Intercept']
```

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be best to concatenate all the CSVs into a single dataframe, and then perform the operation. Clean way to do it, vs. your current approach.

```
import glob.glob
import pandas as pd

file_lst=glob.glob(*.csv)
all_data=pd.DataFrame() #intialize empty dataframe

for file in file_lst:
    dat=pd.read_csv(file)
    all_data.append(dat)
```

This will only work if all CSVs are formatted identically.

Then, with the new concatenated dataframe, you can perform your desired operation.

```
  dat['Y']=dat['m']* dat['x'] +dat['b']
```

Comment: Thanks, it will definitely be a clean way to do it but I have a reason to not concatenate them all together yet.